# FFmpeg android - Fontconfig error : Cannot load default config file

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I am trying to add text over video using ffmpeg in android by

```
"-i", "/storage/emulated/0/videoplayback.mp4", "-vf","drawtext=fontfile=file:///android_asset/fonts/georgia.ttf:text='Text_to_write':fontsize=20:x=100:y=100","-codec:a", "copy", newVideoPath
```

and it showing the error log as

```
ffmpeg version n4.0-39-gda39990 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg
developers
built with gcc 4.9.x (GCC) 20150123 (prerelease)
configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/root/bravobit/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-
--arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/root/bravobit/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-ffprobe --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-yasm --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-linux-perf --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-nonfree --enable-network --enable-avresample --enable-avformat --enable-avcodec --enable-indev=lavfi --enable-hwaccels --enable-ffmpeg --enable-zlib --enable-gpl --enable-small --enable-nonfree --pkg-config=pkg-config --pkg-config-flags=--static --prefix=/root/bravobit/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/root/bravobit/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include
-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/root/bravobit/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-cxxflags=
libavutil56. 14.100 / 56. 14.100
libavcodec     58. 18.100 / 58. 18.100
libavformat    58. 12.100 / 58. 12.100
libavdevice    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
libavfilter     7. 16.100 /  7. 16.100
libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
libswscale5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
libswresample   3.  1.100 /  3.  1.100
libpostproc    55.  1.100 / 55.  1.100
    Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/emulated/0/videoplayback.mp4':
Metadata:
  major_brand     : mp42
  minor_version   : 0
  compatible_brands: isommp42
  creation_time   : 2018-05-19T10:21:06.000000Z
Duration: 00:00:27.07, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 730 kb/s
  Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 639 kb/s, 29.83 fps, 29.83 tbr,
29827 tbn, 59.65 tbc (default)
  Metadata:
    creation_time   : 2018-05-19T10:21:06.000000Z
    handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc. Created on: 05/19/2018.
  Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 96 kb/s (default)
  Metadata:
    creation_time   : 2018-05-19T10:21:06.000000Z
    handler_name    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc. Created on: 05/19/2018.
    Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
    Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
    Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file
    [Parsed_drawtext_0 @ 0xb7af4560] impossible to init fontconfig
    [AVFilterGraph @ 0xb7af3870] Error initializing filter 'drawtext' with args
'fontfile=file:///android_asset/fonts/georgia.ttf:text=Text_to_write:fontsize=20:x=100:y=100'
    Error reinitializing filters!
    Failed to inject frame into filter network: Unknown error occurred
    Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
    Conversion failed!
```

Comment: Try `fontfile=/android_asset/fonts/georgia.ttf` instead of `fontfile=file:///android_asset/fonts/georgia.ttf`.

Comment: i have tried @LordNeckbeard and it is showing the same error log.

Comment: Hi @LordNeckbeard now I used system fonts instead of font fom asset and is working.  But It is only showing the background box not showing text.  "-i", sample.mp4, "-vf", "drawtext=fontfile=/system/fonts/SamsungSans-Num3L.ttf:text=Text_to_write:fontcolor=white:fontsize=100:box=1:boxcolor=black@0.5:boxborderw=5:x=(w-text_w)/2: y=(h-text_h)/2", "-codec:a", "copy", newVideoPath

Comment: It worked. Can we add Html as overlay text like "Sample <span style="color: rgb(255, 69, 218);">text <b><u>one</u></b></span>"

Comment: Should be asked as a new question.

Comment: How can I know the right font file path please?

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the drawtext filter with the fontconfig_file. 
see the answer 
[FFMpeg drawtext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52641011/ffmpeg-error-initializing-filter-drawtext-on-android-project/54183541#54183541)

Answer (score 0):

Use `fontfile=/android_asset/fonts/georgia.ttf` instead of `fontfile=file:///android_asset/fonts/georgia.ttf`.

The `file://` is unnecessary.

Comment: Is there a way to send you a private message or email?